# How to map Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A differently?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

In a terminal, one cannot distinguish <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as they both emit the same key code, so I can see why Vim can't do it. But gVim, being an X application, can differentiate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Is there any way to map those two things differently?

For starters, I'd like to do something like the following: Make "paste from clipboard" work like Gnome terminal, while keeping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to the visual mode.

```
:nmap <C-S-V> "+gP
```

Comment: It's possible: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim

Comment: @vivoconunxino That link makes no mention of adding a shift modifier to ctrl-a.

Comment: With `modifyOtherKeys` feature it's possible by default, see [key bindings - How to map <C-i> separate from <Tab>? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-map-c-i-separate-from-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1) -- and nowadays gVim supports this by default as well.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Gvim doesn't do it because vim cannot do it (under normal circumstances).  Sorry, but that's just how it is.

---

However...

Some terminals (e.g., xterm and iterm2) can be configured to send an arbitrary escape sequence for any combination of keys.

For example, add the following to `.Xresources` for xterm to send `<Esc>[65;5u` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. You can then map that in Vim to `<C-S-a>`.  (65 is the decimal Unicode value for shift-a and 5 is the bit for the ctrl modifier.  The u in this case stands for "unicode".)

```
! .Xresources
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>a: string(0x1b) string("[65;5u")
```

iTerm and [u]rxvt can also be configured to do this (examples not provided).

More info: http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/

Comment: To remap multiple keys, look at [this document](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xterm/XTerm): Separate key entries with `\n`. Use backslash to split lines. E.g. to also map <kbd>C-S-B</kbd> and <kbd>C-S-F</kbd> use this: `XTerm*vt100.translations: #override Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>a: string(0x1b) string("[65;5u") \n Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>b: string(0x1b) string("[66;5u") \n Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>f: string(0x1b) string("[70;5u")`

Comment: For completeness sake, maybe add to the answer also how to map this in vi? E.g. `map <ESC>[66;5u   :echo "ctrl-shift-b received"<CR>` to map ctrl-shift-b to print a message in the status line. On AskUbuntu there was a similar Q and I've [summarized](http://askubuntu.com/a/677070/28323) this.

Comment: If you are scratching your head: I have written a more detailed and complete Q&A inspired in this answer, with several several examples. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241

Answer (score 11):

As already pointed out, there are no ways to map `<C-S-A>` differently from `<C-A>`.

However, using tools like [`autokey`](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/FAQ) (for linux & windows) or [`autohotkey`](http://autohotkey.com/) (for windows), you can remap `<C-S-A>` to send a different key-stroke(s) for specific applications.

e.g. On my system, I have this setting in `autokey`:

```
$ cat ~/.config/autokey/data/gnome-terminal/ctrlshifta-gnome-terminal.py
#ctrl+shift+a sends '<S-F1>a'
keyboard.send_keys("<shift>+<f1>a") # Note that `f` in `f1` needs to be in lower case.
```

Assign it these properties:

1. keyboard-shortcut as `ctrl+shift+a`
2. window class: `gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal`

Then your `~/.vimrc` can create mapping for `<S-F1>a` to do whatever you want.

---

Notes:

1. I have used `<S-F1>` as kind of leader key for detecting `<C-S>`. This was because my terminal did not accept `<F13>`-`<F37>` etc keys. If your application supports it, (`gvim` does I think) using those keys is recommended.
2. I mainly `vim` in `gnome-terminal`. So I used `window class = gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal` as filter. Modify it to use `gvim` if you want. `autokey` supports a button for capturing any other window's properties like class/title.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Theres lots of stuff out there about using Autokey for key remapping but no actual instructions on how to do it. Finally your answer does that. I can't believe no one else has upvoted you.

Comment: God damn autokey! I did everything I could but I couldn't get it installed on my ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `apt install autokey-gtk` ?

Comment: Before installing extra software, you might check to see if your window manager handles this directly.  For example, in i3 my .config has this:
`bindsym --release Control+Shift+h exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers comma w m h`, which presses `,wmh` when I press `<C-S-h>`, and then vim knows how to handle `,wmh`

Comment: ^^ This is good too.
However, I wanted to limit the keys-translation to only gnome-terminal or gvim. Not other apps. Other applications should continue to receive `<C-S-H>` when I press that.

Comment: autokey was a lifesaver for me. Saved me hours of work and debugging. How can I buy you a beer?

Answer (score 8):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Answer (score 5):

If what bothers you is loosing existing C-V functionality, you can use C-Q instead. See, :help CTRL-V-alternative.

Answer (score 4):

NeoVim now offers this functionality for both its terminal and gui clients. See [:h nvim-features-new](http://neovim.org/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features-new)

Comment: Not quite, unless you enable CSI codes in your terminal. The CTRL-SHIFT variants that Neovim _does_ support out of the box are mostly non-printable characters (examples listed at http://neovim.org/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features-new ). However, *meta* chords (including `<m-s-...>` variants) *do* mostly work completely out of the box.

Comment: That document says `ALT (|META|) chords always work (even in the |TUI|). Map |<M-| with any key: <M-1>, <M-BS>, <M-Del>, <M-Ins>, <M-/>, <M-\>, <M-Space>, <M-Enter>, etc. Case-sensitive: <M-a> and <M-A> are two different keycodes.` There's a line break before the "Case-sensitive:" part, making this ambiguous. Thanks for the correction, @JustinM.Keyes. Also, vim 8.1 appears to differentiate between `<M-a>` and `<M-A>` as well.

Comment: @justin-m-keyes `<c-s-l>` is perfectly distinguished from `<c-l>` in `Konsole` without any extra hassle

Comment: Corrected URL from first comment: https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, you get the same keycode. So the only way to distinguish them is to check the state of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in your event handling function.  Of course, if you have more than 0.5 second delay between keypress and processing, you'll miss some hits.

Comment: I guess the point of my question was that given that gvim is capable of making such a distinction (even though plain vim cannot), is there any gvim-specific extension that I could rely on to differentiate Ctrl+Shift+V vs Ctrl+V.

Comment: how to check the state of Shit key? I searched, but didn’t find anything even remotely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most terminal emulators treat control plus shift simply as control by default. Instead, you usually map those key combinations to an escape sequence and listen to that inside the terminal application.

**Step 1:** Configure your terminal emulator to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to the sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>.

Your terminal emulator is the program that shows the actual window of the terminal. When accessing a server via SSH, the terminal emulator is a program on your local machine. Binding keys works differently in different terminal emulators. For example:

- For urxvt, add `URxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-A: \033A` to the `~/.Xresources` configuration file and reload it with `xrdb ~/.Xresources`.
- For iTerm2, open Preferences -> Keys, add an entry, and bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to the action "Send Escape Sequence" and type `A` into the field below.

**Step 2:** Bind <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> to a command in Vim.

Add the key mapping to your `~/.vimrc` configuration and reload it with `:source ~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <esc>a your command here
```

Answer (score 0):

shift + char = Capital of that Char

```
lowercase
<C-a> -> <C-a>

uppercase
<C-S-a> -> <C-A>
```