# easier way to navigate between vim split panes

Tags: vim, navigation

I am using `NERDTree` on vim and usually open files with `i`

Is there an easy way to switch between different panes? Currently I use `CTRL+W+W` to move from one pane to another.

Comment: I realize this is answered, but did you know you can use `CTRL+W, [hjkl]` to navigate the panes/frames? That way if you have 4-6 windows open, you don't have to hit `CTRL+W,W` over and over. I like overthink's keybindings, but then again I enjoy consistency across systems, and when I get used to keybindings I have a hard time relearning them. If I started using CTRL-H to go left, I'd probably end up hitting CTRL-H on systems w/o the keybinding, which actually prints the backspace character by default. Hell I used to press CTRL-H to delete things because the backspace didn't work on my machine!

Comment: `CTRL+W, [hjkl]` to navigate the panes works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: The CTRL+W… mappings are problematic, because CTRL+W closes tabs in browsers and other applications. Sometimes a different window is focused than you thought and then … curses.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Long ago I found a [tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_between_Vim_window_splits_easily) (once on vim.org, now on wikia, apparently) that I've stuck with.  Remap `ctrl-[hjkl]` to navigate splits.  It has served me well.

```
" Use ctrl-[hjkl] to select the active split!
nmap <silent> <c-k> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-j> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-h> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-l> :wincmd l<CR>
```

Comment: I've had similar commands in my .vimrc for ages and can't live without them. Mine are variations, like `map <C-J> <C-w>j<C-w>_` and `map <C-H> <C-w>h<C-w>\|` The `_` and `|` additions force the split to its full width or height when I switch.

Comment: I don't know why but when changing to the `h` direction my destination window was being messed up. Since the `:wincmd` only makes difference off the normal mode and the mappings are used exactly in the normal mode, I have replaced `nmap <silent> <c-h> :wincmd h<CR>` for `nnoremap <silent> <c-h> <c-w>h`

Comment: I strongly recommend remapping caps lock to ctrl also. It makes using this answer even easier.

Comment: @RafaelRendonPablo I've used it successfully in various terminals: urxvt, gnome-terminal, maybe others.  Is it possible your terminal application is trapping Ctrl?

Comment: Mm, maybe, I am using `tmux` and it uses `Ctrl + a` as prefix, I'll try disabling `tmux`. Thanks :)

Comment: Comes for free with amix/vimrc

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old question, but I have a perfect way. Using the number of the split.

`split_number C-w C-w`

The panes are numbered from `top-left` to `bottom-right` with the first one getting the number `1`.

for example to go to split number 3 do this `3 C-w C-w`, press `Ctrl-w` twice.

Comment: With simple search I found that splits are numbered from top-left to bottom-right.

Comment: Great! `3 ctrl-w ctrl-w`

Comment: "With simple search I found that splits are numbered from top-left to bottom-right." Yes, and indexing starts at 1.

Comment: It is never to late to share nice info like this -- thanks a lot, Nafaa

Comment: Any idea how to map this to something shorter like `<C-split_number>`? E.g., I'd want `<C-3>` to navigate to the 3rd split

Answer (score 22):

I prefer hitting single keys over hitting key-chords. The following maps pane movement to arrow keys:

```
" Smart way to move between panes
map <up> <C-w><up>
map <down> <C-w><down>
map <left> <C-w><left>
map <right> <C-w><right>
```

Answer (score 3):

Key mappings are definitely the way to go. I use the mappings mentioned by overthink. I also include the following mappings in my vimrc to move the splits themselves.

```
" Move the splits arround!
nmap <silent> <c-s-k> <C-W>k                                                                                                                       
nmap <silent> <c-s-j> <C-W>j                                                                                                                       
nmap <silent> <c-s-h> <C-W>h                                                                                                                       
nmap <silent> <c-s-l> <C-W>l
```

This makes it so that if the split opens in the wrong spot (lets say the left side and I want it on the right) I go to that split and hit `<C-S-l>` and the split moves where I want it to.

Comment: I thought that Vim sees <c-k> as the same ascii code as <c-s-k>. So doing the above will override the prior mappings.

Comment: I actually use the arrow keys so that could be

Comment: This indeed jams up the accepted answer's mapping. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/. You could use something like this instead: "nmap <silent> <leader><c-k> :wincmd K<CR>" and equivalent for J, H, L.

Answer (score 3):

I have mapped `ctrl+w ctrl+w` to `<tab>` (under normal mode as in normal mode tab does not have any use)and that's have made my life easier as now I can switch between panes easily by pressing `<tab>`.

For switching to a particular pane, I can press `<i> + <tab>` to switch between panes as split window panes also got their own number which can replace i.

Ex. i = 1,2...n.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be consistent with changing tabs via gt & gT, I'm currently trying out the g mappings for changing splits.  I tend to hit the shift key as I go for the Ctrl key so this helps me avoid that mistake until I get better at not doing so.

```
nnoremap gh <C-W><C-H>
nnoremap gj <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap gk <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap gl <C-W><C-L>
```

Answer (score 2):

Very easy way of achieving it. Type this shortcut twice, and that should work

```
ctrl+w ctrl+w
```

Comment: In the question: `Currently I use CTRL+W+W to move from one pane to another.` So...

Answer (score 0):

When using vim inside a browser `ctrl + w` is problematic because it causes the browser tab to close. I sometimes use vim this way when connecting to a server through [Apache Guacamole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guacamole).

## :wincmd

Vim's `:help wincmd` page explains that `:wincmd` or its shortcut `:winc` can be used to move between splits:

> Note: All CTRL-W commands can also be executed with :wincmd,
> for those places where a Normal mode command
> can't be used or is inconvenient.

For example to move left, down, up, right:

```
:winc h
:winc j
:winc k
:winc l
```

- Inspired by this answer on vi stack exchange https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3737/6671
- As explained by overthink in another answer, another solution is to remap `ctrl h` to move to the left split and similarly with the down, up and right moves by entering the following in your `.vimrc`

  ```
  tnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
  tnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
  tnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
  tnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
  ```