# Vim binding to execute function

Tags: vim, key-bindings, vim-plugin

The vim binding I have created works well enough, although I would like the binding to actually execute the function for me. What currently happens is I enter the binding and my function shows up in the `:` prompt, then I press enter to activate the function. Is there some way to include the return character in my binding?

Here is the binding:

```
map <C-C> :call myfunc()
```

when I press ctrl+c, `call myfunc()` shows up in the `:` prompt and I can press enter to activate the function. Is there some way for me to simple press ctrl-c to activate myfunc?

Is there some way for me to add the return character to this

Edit: I tried to recreate this, and now the prompt doesn't show up. I want to create a key binding so that when I press ctrl+c, or ideally ctrl+shift+c, myfunc() is executed.

Comment: Beware that `<C-c>` is used by the interrupt signal.  It's highly recommended to leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
map <C-C> :call myfunc()<CR>
```

`CR` is `Carriage return` or `Enter`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to bind cmd+shift+c? `map <C-S-C>` isn't working for me.

Comment: Follow this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/how-to-map-ctrla-and-ctrlshifta-differently