# Vim: Cannot use Control+Shift+(Left or Right) to select word

Tags: vim

On Windows, within the graphical version of Vim, I an use `Control+Shift+Left` (or `Right`) to select a word while in insert mode.

In order to make sure that nothing is causing it to fail, I first stopped any initialisation files from loading:

`vim -u NONE`

Then, within Vim, `:behave mswin`, which sets up all these shift selections etc.

Why does it work in `gvim` and not in `vim`.  I can ensure that it is nothing on my computer, as I have stopped all scripts, run `vim` in vanilla command prompt, etc, and it still does not work.  I have reproduced the problem on a different computer too.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found is that when using `:behave mswin` in console Vim, you can use `Shift-Right` to select a single character, but then use `Control-Right` (i.e. no `Shift`) to select the next word.

However, I have the habit of using `Control-Shift` to select words, therefore I wrote the following AutoHotkey script to enable this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2 ; for partial matching of Window Title

#If WinActive("ahk_exe vim.exe") or ((WinActive("ahk_exe cmd.exe") or WinActive("ahk_exe powershell.exe") or WinActive("ahk_exe ConEmu64.exe")) and WinActive("- VIM"))

<^<+Left::
    SendInput +{Left}
    SendInput +{Right}
    SendInput ^{Left}
return 

<^<+Right::
    SendInput +{Right}
    SendInput +{Left}
    SendInput ^{Right}
return 

#If
```

Answer (score 1):

To have `Ctrl+Shift+Left` and `Ctrl+Shift+Right` behave as described in your question you could try:

```
if has('gui_running')                                                           
    ;                                                                           
else                                                                            
    inoremap <c-s-left> <c-o>db                                                 
    inoremap <c-s-right> <c-o>de                                                
endif
```

The answers to this question: [How to map Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/how-to-map-ctrla-and-ctrlshifta-differently) explain why `Ctrl-Shift-Key` will not work in certain terminals.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the link to that question.  I tried your solution and it did not work. In Windows, `Control+Shift+<Key>` CAN be sent to the terminal. Otherwise PSReadline (PowerShell module) wouldn't work. I believe Vim simply does not allow `Control+Shift+<Key>` when using the console `vim` on the Windows platform -- it is probably compiled as such and no configuration can enable it.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. As explained by Ingo Karkat in the same link provided above, `Ctrl-Shift-<Key>` seems to be a known problem with no present solution.