# can't get these control keys to work in vim

Tags: vim

I am looking at part of this vimrc file from Ben Frain

https://gist.github.com/benfrain/f09dd39e66fe2da9cf0a

```
" Allow line movement on wraps with CTRL+usual {{{
vmap <C-j> gj
vmap <C-k> gk
vmap <C-h> g$
vmap <C-6> g^
vmap <C-0> g^
nmap <C-j> gj
nmap <C-k> gk
nmap <C-4> g$
nmap <C-6> g^
nmap <C-0> g^
" }}}
```

I do notice an issue in that list e.g. ctrl-k already does gk. So when that works it's not from his mapping.

I am using macvim

Even if I try something simple

```
~/.vim$ cat vimrc
nmap <C-0> aaaa
~/.vim$
```

or

```
~/.vim$ cat vimrc
nmap <C-0> aaaa
vmap <C-0> aaaa
~/.vim$
```

it's not working, it's not mapping ctrl-0 to the typing of 'aaaa'

I've tried with `/usr/local/bin/vim`(that's macvim installed via `brew cask install macvim`) and i've tried `/usr/bin/vim`(that's the vim that comes preinstalled). So it makes no difference which vim I use.

And i'd like to know which, if any, ctrl keys can be mapped.

I have heard that it's a bad idea to map ctrl keys, maybe 'cos many are in use, and that it's better to use the leader key, whose default is backslash. So . `map <leader>0 aaaa` . and that works, but i'm still curious re the mapping of ctrl.

Comment: Related question [vim - How to map Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A differently? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506764/how-to-map-ctrla-and-ctrlshifta-differently/2179779#2179779)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't "see" all available Ctrl-something combinations. Vim is developed for a Unix terminal and those terminals don't provide all Ctrl-keys to the application.

To test if a ctrl combination is mappable, do the following:

Open Vim and change into insert mode. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> followed by the Ctrl combination you want to map. If something is displayed, the Ctrl combination is mappable.

Examples:

- If you hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd> the character `^k` is displayed (usually in light blue). So <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd> is mappable.
- If you hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd> nothing is displayed. So <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd> is **not** mappable.
- If you hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl-3</kbd> the character `^[` is displayed. So ... <kbd>Ctrl-3</kbd> is equal to <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: any idea about finding out which command keys are mappable? (the command key on a macbook keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

This page mentions difference between xmap, vmap and nmap [https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_1)](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1))

> ```
> :map <-- (presumably display all maps)
>
> :nmap - Display normal mode maps
> :imap - Display insert mode maps
> :vmap - Display visual and select mode maps
> :smap - Display select mode maps
> :xmap - Display visual mode maps
> :cmap - Display command-line mode maps
> :omap - Display operator pending mode maps
> ```

and

> ```
> nmap, nnoremap, nunmap          Normal mode
> imap, inoremap, iunmap          Insert and Replace mode
> vmap, vnoremap, vunmap          Visual and Select mode
> xmap, xnoremap, xunmap          Visual mode
> smap, snoremap, sunmap          Select mode
> cmap, cnoremap, cunmap          Command-line mode
> omap, onoremap, ounmap          Operator pending mode
> ```

It looks like you can't do the numbers with ctrl.

nmap is for normal mode so to type aaaa, you need to type iaaaa so as to go into insert mode first. So, with nmap, mapping  to iaaaa to get 'aaaa' typed.

You can try `nmap <C-a> iaaaa` all the way up to `<C-z>`, and get a response from most of them. You can do `map <C-a> aaaa` or `:map <C-a> aaaa`